# Stop jQuery animated progress bar

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I would like to stop the progress bar by clicking the button, but the animation always finishes to the defined 50%. what am i missing?

```js
animation = ""

var getPercent1 = .5; 
var getProgressWrapWidth1 = $('.progress-wrap').width();
var progressTotal1 = getPercent1 * getProgressWrapWidth1;
  
 // .stop() used to prevent animation queueing
 $('.progress-bar').stop().animate({
  left: progressTotal1
 }, 3000);
 
 animation = setTimeout(function() {
  var getPercent2 = .8;
  var getProgressWrapWidth2 = $('.progress-wrap').width();
  var progressTotal2 = getPercent2 * getProgressWrapWidth2;   
  
  $('.progress-bar').stop().animate({
   left: progressTotal2
  }, 3000);
 }, 3100); 
 
function stopProgress() {
 clearTimeout(animation);
 $('progress-bar').stop();
}
```

```css
.progress{width:100%;height:50px;border-radius:0}.progress-wrap{background:#18AC56;margin:20px 0;overflow:hidden;position:relative;-webkit-transition:background 1s;-moz-transition:background 1s;-o-transition:background 1s;transition:background 1s;}.progress-wrap .progress-bar{background:#ddd;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-wrap progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress"></div>
</div> 

<button type="button" onClick="stopProgress()">click to stop</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing a little '.'

```
$('progress-bar').stop();
```

should be

```
$('.progress-bar').stop();
```

side note: I recommend that you use Velocity.js for your animation... it's got the same syntax as jquery's animate but is much more efficient.